# Как отправить event в Google Analytics 4?

Tags: база-данных, события, firebase, google-analytics

Подскажите, как получить ивенты в Гугл Аналитику (Firebase) из внешней системы?
Буду краток:

1. пользователь зарегистрировался на продукте через сайт или приложение
2. В базе данных продукта создается ивент, к примеру user_registration

Вот этот user_registration я хочу отправить в свою Гугл Аналитику. Подскажите, как это сделать?